# Out of memory error : StringBuilder.append throwing OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that fetches data from a bluetooth device. But sometimes it throws **OOM error** while performing some operation

Here is the code

The Following way I am storing the data in an `ArrayList<String>`

```
private ArrayList<String> dataList; 
if (response.compareTo("Some Filter") != 0 //response is of String type
{
    dataList.add(response);
}
```

And in the below `for each` loop it throws OOM error

```
for (String s : dataList) { 
if(s.length()>8)
    dataList.set(dataList.indexOf(s), s.substring(8));  
else
    dataList.set(dataList.indexOf(s), "");
}

String downloadedData = "";
for (String s : dataList) {
    downloadedData += s; //This one is the 280th line throwing OOM
}
```

So far I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537550/android-out-of-memory-error-stringbuilder) post but it gives solutions for reading data in json or web response

[And i know OOM error can't be handled but prevented by following a good Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544919/android-how-to-handle-out-of-memory-exception)

And there are also these two Callbacks for Android

1. [onLowMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html#onLowMemory())
2. [onTrimMemory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory(int))

But i am not sure how to go for the solution !!

The crash Stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 106990 byte allocation with 5840 free bytes and 5KB until OOM
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
 java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216) 
 at Class_name.java:280.
```

Any help is appreciated `:)`

Comment: Was that indeed line 280? Show the previous line too.

Comment: What's the size of your dataList, IMO it all depends on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: `if (response.compareTo("Some Filter") != 0 )` that is just weird, you can just use `equals` method.

Then you are adding response to the list, and then you are reducing length of all responses in a list if they are higher than 8 (also, you did `substring(8)`, that trims the first 8 letters and I think you wanted to preserve first 8 letters and delete the rest, if yes then do this `substring(0, 8)`).

My answer is: why not just take care of the things you are doing in a `for-each` when you are adding it to a list? It would be a lot easier and it would be better performance-wise, and would probably fix your error.

Also, I'm not sure if you are initializing your list, maybe you just forgot to paste it (all you have is `private ArrayList<String> dataList;`), but that's how you make a new list:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

First your loop should use

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); ++i) {
    String s = dataList.get(i);
    dataList.set(i, s.length() > 8 ? s.substring(8) : "");  
}
```

And the error points in another direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try it is working

```
 ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
 String response = "CVMKVLC";
    if (response.compareTo("Some Filter") != 0 ) {
         //response is of String type     
         dataList.add(response);
    }

    for (String s : dataList) { //This line throws OOM
       if(s.length()>8)
           dataList.set(dataList.indexOf(s), s.substring(8));
       else
           dataList.set(dataList.indexOf(s), "");
       }
    }
```